# Homeomorphisms of product spaces: an example

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, examples

In the first of these lectures (http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/4436) given by M. Freedman he says that there exists (compact metric) spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\times S^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times S^{1}$ but $X\times \mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $Y\times\mathbb{R}$.

Does anyone know an example of such spaces?

Comment: See [Does $X\times S^1\cong Y\times S^1$ imply that $X\times\mathbb R\cong Y\times\mathbb R$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/396608) on math.SE